# Problem understanding a specific proof of the derivative of cosine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, proof-explanation

In the book *Calculus made easy* by Silvanus Thompson there is a rather strange proof for the derivative of cosine, which I would like some help understanding.

Proof:

$$ y = cos\ \theta $$

$$ cos\ \theta = sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)\ \Rightarrow \ dy=d(sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)) = cos(\frac\pi2-\theta)\times d(-\theta) = cos(\frac\pi2-\theta)\times (-d\theta) \\ \frac{dy}{d\theta}= -cos(\frac\pi2-\theta) \iff \frac{dy}{d\theta}=-sin\ \theta
$$

The problem is that I don't understand what properties $d$ has which allows this reformulation: $d(sin(\frac\pi2-\theta)) = cos(\frac\pi2-\theta)\times d(-\theta)$ Thought $d$ that it only meant "small part of something".

Note that I have seen and understand other proofs of the derivative, it's this particular one I would like an explanation of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $df=\frac{df}{d\theta}d\theta$. He just used twice chain rule

Comment: That's kind of bizarre. The author is using the derivative of $sin$ as a known to determine the derivative of $cos$. Maybe he already demonstrated how to find the derivative of $sin$

Comment: @user2460798 you are using double angle formula to derive the derivative of sin. You can also do the same to derive the derivative of cos. But if you know the derivative of sin, this is only 2 line to proof for cos.

Comment: No it is using a reflection formula. (A double angle formula looks like $sin(2\theta) = \dots$). What I found strange was that if the author has already given the derivation of $sin$, why wouldn't he use a similar derivation for $cos$. Although the way he did it he does demonstrate another technique.

Comment: @user2460798 I said one would use double angle formula to derive derivative of SIN! Not cos in OP's post. Using double angle formula is more complicated

Comment: Actually you said "you are using double angle formula". I knew I wasn't using double angle formula for anything. So I was assuming "you" meant third person, as in the OP.